# Rails 4 raises ArgumentError when using some syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In `Ubuntu`, `ruby 2.0.0p247` and `Rails 4.0.0` when I use the following syntax

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimun: 5 }
```

I get the exception `Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.`.

Also, if I write

```
validates :title, :presence => true, :minimun => 5
```

I get the exception `Unknown validator: 'MinimunValidator'`.

How can I rewrite this so it works? As [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation) says this should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo (`minimun` instead of `minimum`) which is why the error:

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use minimum instead of minimun...